# Deploy NodeJS server on production server with grunt

Tags: node.js

I'm currently developing a web application with NodeJS.

Grunt is used for deployment and I used to run the server using following shell command.

```
 NODE_ENV="development" grunt
```

This automatically merges, minifies and starts the node server.

On production server, I run following command to start the server in production environment.

```
 NODE_ENV="production" grunt
```

This starts the server, but when I disconnect from the server (from ssh), it stops after sometime.

Is it possible to keep the NodeJS server running using grunt-deploy npm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to daemonize the node process.  There are a lot of ways to do this and a lot of libraries out there that will handle this for you such as [`forever`](https://github.com/foreverjs/forever) and [`pm2`](https://github.com/Unitech/pm2).

As for how you do this specifically, it depends on many factors like what `grunt` is actually doing, the availability of libraries, etc. etc.  You could use [`grunt-forever`](https://github.com/bustardcelly/grunt-forever) to use `forever` within Grunt (this seems to be an old library, though).

`PM2` also has [documentation on deployments](https://github.com/Unitech/PM2/blob/2587c46835911d31391118c0d7c51ac3b982154d/ADVANCED_README.md#deployment).  You can update the `script` to be `/path/to/grunt` and pass the tasks to run as arguments.

The simplest solution may be to use

```
nohup NODE_ENV=production grunt &
```

...but this has not worked consistently for me in the past.